# Editing object with javascript/underscore, adding new items if don't exist already

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

So I am pulling in an object that I want to "edit", with a bit of help I have a function that finds the item i'm looking for and replaced the value. What I did no account for when building this was if the items don't exist yet.

So right now the function looks like this :

```
   myFunction = function(moduleName, stateName, startVar){
    //currentState brought in from factory controlling it
     var currentState = StateFactory.current();
    _.each(currentState, function(item) {
                if (item.module === moduleName) {
                  _.each(item.customUrl, function(innerItem) {
                    if (_.has(innerItem, stateName)) {
                      innerItem[stateName] = startVar;
                    }
                  });
                }
              });  
   }
```

So - this does a great job of replacing the startVar value, assuming it already exists. I need to add some levels of checks to make sure the items exist (and if they don't add them in).

So, for reference, this is what the currentState looks like

```
 [{
 "module": "module1",
 "customUrl": [
    { "mod1": "2" },
    { "mod2": "1" }
]
 }, {
"module": "module2",
"customUrl": [
    { "mod3": "false" },
    { "mod4": "5" }
]
 }
 ];
```

And so if i passed

```
 myFunction("module1","mod1",3);
```

This works great, however if I pass

```
myFunction("module5","mod8","false");
```

Or maybe something in between like

```
 myFunction("module1","mod30","false");
```

This function will not handle that scenario. I could use some helpe wrapping my head around how to tackle this problem. Also, am using underscore (if it is required to help). Thank you for taking the time to read!

As mentioned by Phari - something to the effect of this

```
  currentState[moduleName].customUrl[stateName] = startVar;
```

I was thinking I could just create the object and just _.extend, but because it is an array of objects that wont quite work.

Here's what I mean :

```
  var tempOb = {"module" : moduleName, "customUrl" : [{stateName : startVar}]};

  _.extend(currentState, tempOb);
```

Doesn't quite work right with an array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that all you need to do is remove the `if` statement:

```
                if (_.has(innerItem, stateName)) {
                  innerItem[stateName] = startVar;
                }
```

should become simply:

```
                  innerItem[stateName] = startVar;
```

Then if the property is not present, it will be added.  If it is already present, it will be overwritten.

**EDIT**: to handle absence at top level:

```
myFunction = function(moduleName, stateName, startVar){
//currentState brought in from factory controlling it
 var currentState = StateFactory.current();
 var found = false;
_.each(currentState, function(item) {
            if (item.module === moduleName) {
              found = true;
              _.each(item.customUrl, function(innerItem) {
                if (_.has(innerItem, stateName)) {
                  innerItem[stateName] = startVar;
                }
              });
            }
          });  
    if ( ! found ) {
        var newItem = {
            module: moduleName,
            customUrl: []
        };
        var newInnerItem = {};
        newInnerItem[stateName] = startVar;
        newItem.customUrl.push(newInnerItem);
        currentState.push(newItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, great! What about the levels above it?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand what you mean, can you clarify?

Comment: So this solves the lowest level, changing or creating new items inside the customURl, but what if there isn't and existing top level (the object), so what if i passed like myFunction("module5","mod8","false"), module5 does not exist, nor anything inside of it. Or what if i pass something like myFunction("module1","mod30","false"), where the module exists, but not the item inside customUrl?

Comment: So something like (this doesn't work but) - currentState[moduleName].customUrl[stateName] = startVar; .